# draw image of canvas working with db image src but not with local images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, html5-canvas

I am trying to load a image onto canvas, my code works fine when i input `image.src="https://somelink"` but throws a GET error when i try to import using `image.src="../public/vercel.svg`. my code :

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";


const Canvas = (props) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
        // load image
        const image = new Image()
        image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/sFVCGfd/map.png"
        
        const canvas = canvasRef.current
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        // our first draw
        context.fillStyle = "#000000"
        context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height)
        console.log(image)
       
        image.onload = () => {
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
        }
    }, [])
    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...props} width={288} height={480} />
}

export default Canvas
```

is there any way to get around this?

Comment: You cannot access the server's file system from inside the browser. Use `import Vercel from "../public/vercel.svg";` then `image.src = Vercel;` (it might work differently for Next though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you must add your web site in next.config.js

```
 images: {
    formats: ['image/webp'],
    domains: [
      http://i.ibb.co
    ],
  },
```

for local remove "public"

```
image.src="/vercel.svg"
```